# Reverse geocoding in QGIS Graphical Modeller

Tags: qgis, point, geocoding, qgis-modeler, reverse-geocoding

I would like to add addresses to the attributes of a series of points using the Graphical Modeller.

I can use the [GeoCoding Plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/GeoCoding/) to get the address by clicking manually but would like it to be automatic. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a possibility of using a ["Field calculator"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#field-calculator) inside the Graphical Modeler.

Let's assume there is a point layer `'test'` with some features in it, see the image below

[image: input]

Thereafter I created a simple model for [reverse geocoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_geocoding) as following:

[image: model]

*where* a "Field calculator" possess the following parameters

[image: field_calc]

In the 'Formula' tab apply this expression:

```
reverse_geocoding(y(transform($geometry,@project_crs,'EPSG:4326')), x(transform($geometry,@project_crs,'EPSG:4326')))
```

A custom `reverse_geocoding()` function defined as

```py
import geopy
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from geopy.point import Point
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

locator = Nominatim(user_agent="MyReverseGeocoder", timeout=10)

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def reverse_geocoding(lat, lon, feature, parent):
    try:
        location = locator.reverse(Point(lat, lon))
        return location.raw['display_name']
    except:
        pass
```

Here the Nominatim geocoder (free to choose) from the GeoPy geocoding Python library was used, for more details, please check [the documentation](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#nominatim). Also, coordinates of point features should be transmitted [as a pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57770044/valueerror-must-be-a-coordinate-pair-or-point), otherwise, you may get this error `ValueError: Must be a coordinate pair or Point`. Therefore `from geopy.point import Point` was used.

Mind that additionally installation of `geopy` library inside the QGIS is required, the *how-to process* described in [Installing 3rd party python libraries for QGIS on Windows](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141320/installing-3rd-party-python-libraries-for-qgis-on-windows), [Installing Python packages in QGIS 3 (for Windows)](https://landscapearchaeology.org/2018/installing-python-packages-in-qgis-3-for-windows/), and [Install QGIS through OSGeo4W](https://www.giscourse.com/install-qgis-through-osgeo4w/) (also applicable for Python packages).

And afterwards, I ran the model with [image: run] (<kbd>F5</kbd> as shortcut) and got the output

[image: result]

P.S. As you can see I used `'display_name'` from the output dictionary `location.raw`, however, other key-value pairs (e.g. `location.raw['address']`) can be extracted from the full geocoder’s response for this result.

---

Another solution that may inspire you with, described in [@csk's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/300619/99589). So, you may try to find and download the reference point data with addresses for your area, and then simply use the ["Join attributes by nearest"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#join-attributes-by-nearest) geoalgorithm in the Graphical Modeler.

---

Some hints on how to perform reverse geocoding (for QGIS versions 3.18 and higher) using QGIS's *"native"* functions, can be found in the [@ThomasG77's implementation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/395415/99589). Discussion about native geocoding including the reverse geocoding described in [Add interface API for geocoders](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/38169).