# Installing Python module using pip via Python console in QGIS 3.22

Tags: qgis, python, installation, qgis-python-console, pip

Import module pip not works:

```
import pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 888, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

How can I install for example Pandas module in Python console?

> QGIS version: 3.22.1-Białowieża
>
> QGIS code revision: 663dcf8fb9
>
> Qt version: 5.15.2
>
> Python version: 3.9.5
>
> GDAL/OGR version: 3.4.0
>
> PROJ version: 8.2.0
>
> EPSG Registry database version: v10.038 (2021-10-21)
>
> GEOS version: 3.10.0-CAPI-1.16.0
>
> SQLite version: 3.35.2
>
> PDAL version: 2.3.0
>
> PostgreSQL client version: 13.0
>
> SpatiaLite version: 5.0.1
>
> QWT version: 6.1.3
>
> QScintilla2 version: 2.11.5
>
> OS version: Windows 10 Version 2009

Comment: Pip is the module for installing python packages from CMD/Terminal, not for installing python packages inside python console. Take a look of [pip official site](https://pypi.org/project/pip/), and check your python installation for knowing were to install new modules

Comment: You can find also some vital details in this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/394695/99589

Answer (score 0):

```
import platform
import subprocess 
import sys

try:
    import pandas
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    if platform.system() == 'Windows':
        subprocess.call([sys.exec_prefix + '/python', "-m", 'pip', 'install', 'pandas'])
    else:
        subprocess.call(['python3', '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'pandas']) 
    import pandas
```

Comment: Does this work for you with QGIS 3.22 on Windows? I get a 
`WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/matplotlib/`